# Node Js Server Images working only on local

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack, image-uploading, imagesource

I am using this code with an application with Node js (and angular 6) to read pictures:

Nodejs server file :

```
    ....
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
..
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
    const cors = require('cors');


    // view engine setup
     app.set('uploads', path.join(__dirname, 'uploads'));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');

    app.use(cors());
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(fileUpload());
    app.use('/uploads', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));


    app.post('/upload', (req, res, next) => {
      console.log(req);
      let imageFile = req.files.file;

      imageFile.mv(`${__dirname}/uploads/${req.body.filename}.jpg`, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(500).send(err);
        }

        res.json({file: `uploads/${req.body.filename}.jpg`});
      });

    })

    // catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      const err = new Error('Not Found');
      err.status = 404;
      next(err);
    });

    // error handler
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      // set locals, only providing error in development
      res.locals.message = err.message;
      res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

      // render the error page
      res.status(err.status || 500);
      res.render('error');
    });

    app.listen(8888, () => {
      console.log('8888');
    });
```

this code is working on local to read pictures.
example:
http://localhost:8888/uploads/02.jpg

But when deploying this code on server
I can't read the files. example:
http://www.mywebsite.com/uploads/image.jpg (image existing)

what I need to do to make this code working on the online website?

Thank you.

Comment: Check permissions of the directory and files, perhaps nodejs process is not allowed to read it.
Also, maybe you need to check your server configuration if you are allowed to read from that directory.

Comment: are you sure that  the image url is correct? did you check the url  to see if __dirname is getting you the correct path in server

Comment: yes, the permission of the folder and pictures is read, write,execute. The folder uploads is on the same directory of the server.js file

Comment: is it that the image does not load in angular only , but loads in browser while visiting direct url in new tab, try visiting that url in new tab of your browser and check if image loads

Comment: also try to make following change in the  code : `app.use('/uploads',express.static('uploads'));`

Comment: @IhebSaad did you check

Comment: Node js  crashes when I launch the images 's server . I am trying to resolve the problem So I can test your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in remote server,

```
sudo chomd -R 777 your_project_folder
```

try it, 
My guess is that permission issue or folder for image is not created.

so, after check error log, if image folder is not created,

first, you should create it,
second, typing this script. it is script that give full permission to all directory of project

Comment: Thank you. It works now ! (I have a problem when opening the port for pictures with the principal port but when I tested it alone. It works )

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer, while seemingly solves OP's issue, poses a serious security threat and should be avoided in production. `chomd -R 777` opens a folder's (and all subfolders, including project files, not only images) for view and modification by everyone. Instead, folder permisisons should be adjusted granulary, just as @akkonrad suggests.

Comment: Thank you. I will take this on onsideration :)